# Invoke helper text method on typing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In the following, there is a MUI textfield method, which has a `helperText` attribute.
I want to invoke that method, when somebody starts typing in the `text field`.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function App() {
 const [inputText, setInputText] = useState(null);
 const [txtLength, setTxtLength] = useState(0);

 const handleChange = (event) => {
   const textValue = event.target.value;
   setInputText(textValue);
   setTxtLength(textValue.length);
 };
 const displayHelperText = () => {
   return `${12 - txtLength} characters left`;
 };
 return (
   <TextField
     onChange={handleChange}
     inputProps={{ maxLength: 12 }}
     helperText={displayHelperText} // Invoke on typing in text field
   />
 );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/helper-text-method-sofl-fbumfr) demo.

Comment: It's JS; you can write whatever helper methods you'd like. If the method depends on external data, however, you still need to pass that data to the helper. You *may* want to *wrap* `<TextField>` in your own component, dig into `<TextField>` internals, etc. There are several options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```
helperText={ txtLength > 0? displayHelperText() : ""}
```

You could potentially use undefined instead of "" for the last portion, I don't know offhand if MUI allows undefined for that prop.

(also I'd just use the string inline, no need for a stand alone displayHelperText function here)